# (Oracle)Splitting strings then averaging at once

Tags: sql, oracle, average

My colum COL1 have sometimes have data such as, '10|20'.
My goal is to split the data if the data have "|". And then averaging them to get 15.
How to modify my code below to add COL2 like this?

```
(Expected results)

COL1      COL2
-------  -------
10        10
10|20     15
10|20|30  20

(My code)
WITH A AS (
SELECT '10' COL1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '10|20' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '10|20|30' FROM DUAL
) SELECT COL1 FROM A  DUAL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a correlated `XMLTABLE` to split the values:

```sql
WITH A AS (
SELECT '10' COL1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10|20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10|20|30' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT col1,
       (
         SELECT AVG( TO_NUMBER( column_value ) )
         FROM   xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(a.col1, '|', '","') || '"'))
       ) AS col2
FROM   A
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> COL1     | COL2
> :------- | ---:
> 10       |   10
> 10|20    |   15
> 10|20|30 |   20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=11c49fd65c77c128b0252faa2d3ed4ef)*

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SQL> with a as
  2    (select '10' col1  from dual union all
  3     select '10|20'    from dual union all
  4     select '10|20|30' from dual
  5    )
  6  select
  7    col1,
  8    avg(to_number(regexp_substr(col1, '[^\|]+', 1, column_value))) col2
  9  from a cross join
 10    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                        connect by level <= regexp_count(col1, '\|') + 1
 12                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 13  group by col1
 14  order by col1;

COL1           COL2
-------- ----------
10               10
10|20            15
10|20|30         20

SQL>
```

What does it do?

Line #8 (with a little help of lines #10 - 12):

- `REGEXP_SUBSTR` part is used to split column to rows
- `TO_NUMBER` converts substring to number
- `AVG` calculates average value

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT '10' text FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '10|20' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '10|20|30' FROM DUAL
) 
SELECT  text,
        avg(to_number(regexp_substr(t.text, '[^\|]+', 1, column_value))) average
    FROM t,
      TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
      (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual
              CONNECT BY instr(t.text, '|', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
      ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
GROUP BY t.text ORDER BY t.text;

TEXT        AVERAGE
-------- ----------
10               10
10|20            15
10|20|30         20
```